# I am trying to deploy a pod in eks cluster but it is showing too many pods, but i have only one pod in that

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95YvF.png)[I am trying to deploy one pod in node but it is in pending state when i describe pod I got too many pods, but i have only one pod in node[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CY5DT.png)

Comment: What do you mean by many pods? I see that in the image you shared, the `kubectl describe` command is run that will display various information about the pod like its annotations, containers, ports, volumes, events etc

Comment: You seem to have included a link to an image in place of your question.  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve], including at least the minimum source code (trimmed Kubernetes YAML manifest) to demonstrate the problem and the actual text of the error or problem you're getting?  This question doesn't seem likely to need a PNG file as part of its explanation.

Comment: Thanks ,  solution was my storage is full and not able deploy any more pods.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As the image suggests, you have too many pods on your nodes. Each node in the cluster normally has a limit to how many pods it is allowed to hold. For example our GKE nodes allow 110 pods per node. The amount of pods you can have on your node is normally detemined by what CIDR range is assigned to it.

Bear in mind the cluster has more pods than just the stuff you deploy. You should check what you actually have deployed in the cluster, and clean up stuff you don't need.

A starting point for your investigation would be to use `kubectl get nodes` to get your nodes then `kubectl describe node {node-name}` to see details of what is actually on the node.

Answer (score -1):

This Worked for me: 
Try setting `priorityClassName: high-priority`. This will evict the low priority pods from the node and will scheduler the pods with higher-priority. Still, if some pods are unscheduled, then you can drain/delete some nodes on which the required pods are not scheduled.