# kubernetes - Why is there a max pods per node?

Tags: kubernetes

Why is there a pod limit in Kubernetes?

It makes intuitive sense to me that there'll be some limitation, but I'm curious to know the specific botteleneck which warrants the limit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I am trying to deploy a pod in eks cluster but it is showing too many pods, but i have only one pod in that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72225955/i-am-trying-to-deploy-a-pod-in-eks-cluster-but-it-is-showing-too-many-pods-but)

Comment: @BlenderFox So the limit is there because of the CIDR range assigned to the node? Yeah, I guess it answere my question. Thanks

Comment: Correct. When you create a cluster, you normally have to assign a range that cluster will use for the pods (each pod will take an IP from that pool). There's only so many IPs in that range, hence the limit. It's rare that you'll use every single IP in that range, but it is possible, hence the limit

Answer (score 4):

The default limit of 110 pods per node is merely a compromise of Kubernetes, I think, not a technical limit.

Some vendors have additional limitations.

For example, on Azure, there's a limit on the number of IP addresses you can assign to a node. So if your Kubernetes cluster is configured to assign a IP address from Azure VNet to each pod, the limit is 30 (See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/configure-azure-cni#maximum-pods-per-node).

On IBM Cloud, if you use IBM Block Storage for persistent volumes, they will be mounted as 'Secondary volumes' on your node, and you can only have 12 of those per node, so that's limit of 12 pods with persistent volumes. It sucks when you hit that limit when scaling up the first time :-(
On other vendors or with other storage classes, this limit is larger: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-limits/